# Find file based on content of entire file, not per line

Tags: search, find, regex

Can I search for files with a rexexp that is matched against the entire file? Let's say that I have these files:

```
//file1
foo
bar

//file2
bar
foo
```

I want to find files that end with "foo". If I use `grep` and the regex `foo$` that will match both files since they both have lines ending with "foo". But I only want to match the second since that is the only case where the entire file ends with "foo".

Comment: Add the end of file char to your regex (would be \Z in perl etc or GNU would be \')

Comment: 'grep -P "foo\Z"' still matches all files

Comment: Does `grep -zP "foo\Z" file*` work for you? (note the `-z` flag)

Comment: No, weird output but still prints all files

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `tail` and `grep` e.g.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n1 "$1" | grep -q "foo"' sh {} \; -print
```

Comment: That solved  the problem in the example but not the real question which was a regexp matched against the entire file. This could only be used to match contents of the last line.  I am sorry if the example was misleading.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson can you give a more realistic example? is it a multi-line regex?

Comment: Lets say that I want to find files with the foo ending. But they may also contain blank lines after the last character. That would be something like "foo\s+$" right?

Answer (score 0):

In perl, option `0` can be use to process the file as single record.

This way try:

```
perl -n0E  'say $ARGV if /foo\s*$/' file*
```

`\s*` is useful to cope with new lines and similar, normally present at the end of the file.

Another similar alternative (gnugrep)

```
grep -lzP 'foo\Z' file*
```